# Server of VMWare virtual machines

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-server

Sory for asking questions like these, but all I can find is how to use a virtual server and that is not what I need.

I need to create a server (VMWare or not) or a super-server, where I can install several virtual machines, linux, windows xp, windows 7... and more than one of each.

Then, I should be able to connect it to a network (this I think I know how to do it) and connect another computer to that server virtual machine.

Is it possible? What software should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. VMWare has a component called Hypervisor which acts like a super operating system. All other operating systems can be installed over it as virtual machines. They can also be connected in a network. The VMWare Hypervisor takes care of sharing of hardware resources among various VMs( similar to how OS manages various processes).

Comment: Do You know the beaver with Thin Clients?

Comment: You can use VMware ESX as a hypervisor and VMware vCenter to manage virtual machines and ESX hosts.  These products are available for download from VMware website and have a 60-day trial period. The VMware vCenter includes a full-featured Thin Client.